# Calling jQuery form validator after anti-SPAM check?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, spam-prevention

This is probably a very basic JavaScript question but I don't know enough yet to know how to do it.

After a successful call to a [basic anti-SPAM solution](http://sourcefirst.wordpress.com/2007/05/02/simple-javascript-captcha/) that requires the user to add two numbers, how can I have the form go on using jQuery's form validator?

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
    var c = a + b
    function DrawBotBoot()
    {
        document.write("R&eacute;sultat de "+ a + " + " + b +"? ");
        document.write("<input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2' size='2'/>");
    }    
    function ValidBotBoot(){
        var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
        if (d == c) return true;        
        return false;
    }
  </script>

  <script>
  //Used by jQuery to validate all form fields
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="send.php" method="post" id="myform">
 <input type="text" maxlength="25" id="name" name="name" class="required"/>
 Are you human?<br />
 <script type="text/javascript">DrawBotBoot()</script>
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Send" onclick="alert(ValidBotBoot());"/> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Validate has a submit handler handler

Try this:

```
 $("#myform").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) { 
           form.submit();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what happens with validate() and how to combine the form validation + anti-spam trick. I'll try to figure it out.